Why can't I sign in with Firebase using thirdweb Auth?
I cloned this repo: https://github.com/thirdweb-example/firebase-auth.git and entered the appropriate environmental variables.
I ran it on my localhost:3001 and then clicked "Sign in with Wallet", but nothing happened. Instead, there are three errors:
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm not sure exactly what those errors mean.
Why are these errors being thrown?
I made sure that all of the environmental variables are correct to initialize Firebase:
export default function initializeFirebaseClient(): {
  db: Firestore;
  auth: Auth;
} {
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  });

  const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

  return {
    db,
    auth,
  };
}

Other than that I have kept the code the same.

Did you notice that the repo is archived with a big warning about how it doesn't work?

This should be closed... don't use deprecated utilities
